# Need help breaking down this sentence: "I took action to make my plan come to fruition."

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence, parts-of-speech, infinitives, subordinate-clauses

So far I have "to make my plan come to fruition" as a subordinate clause, but I'm having trouble defining its components. Is "come to fruition" modifying "plan"? How is the infinitive functioning here?

If anyone can break down the whole sentence that would be super helpful too. Thanks!

Comment: "…bring my plan to fruition" would be the more idiomatic way to say this.

Answer (score 1):

> "to make my plan come to fruition"

Consider "**I make** my plan come to fruition"

I = subject

make  = verb

[my plan] – NP = object

come = verb complement (as part of a causative verb structure)

to fruition [preposition + noun = adverbial modifier]

Now with “I make” replaced by “to make”:

To make = in order (subordinating conjunction) to make = infinitive, and the rest remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I took **action** [*to make my plan come to fruition*]

[To make my plan come to fruition] is a ***non-finite to-infinitival clause***. To be exact '*to make my plan come to fruition'* is a non-finite complement of the noun **action**.

CGEL discusses this on page 1259

> Many nouns license non-finite complements, all to-infinitivals:
>   [image]

It is syntactically similar to:

> [11ib] Kim’s **decision** [*to go to Bon*n] 
>   [11iib] Pat’s **eagerness** [*to help us*] 
>   [11iii] the **opportunity** [*to make a quick profit*] 
>   
>   CGEL, p. 1259

---

On a deeper level, it can be analysed as a catenative construction.

## Catenative construction:

> **Non-finite clauses** occur in a wide range of functions, as complements, modifiers, and supplements. One function that is worth drawing attention to here is that of catenative complement in clause structure:
>
> [2iia] Max seemed [*to like them*]
>   [2iia] Everyone believed Kim [*to be guilty*]
>
> [2ib] Jill intended [*to join the army*] 
>   [2iib] She asked me [*to second her motion*]
>
> The term ‘catenative’ reflects the fact that this construction is recursive (repeatable), so that we can have a chain, or concatenation, of verbs followed by non-finite complements, as in:
>
> *She intends to try to persuade him to help her decorate her flat*
>
> (CGEL; p. 65)

In the OP’s example, the catenative construction looks like this:

> I **took** action [to **make** my plan] | **come** [to fruition]

Comment: I disagree. 'Bob's action [to make his plan come to fruition]' is unidiomatic at best. Here, it's 'take action' that takes a to-infinitival clause. 'Bob took action [to make his plan come to fruition]' =  'Bob acted decisively  [to make his plan come to fruition]'. 'Take steps/action'  are multi-word (verbo-nominal) verbs [[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20action), [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/take_action)] that may be followed by a to-infinitival clause. Compare 'Holmes took care to avoid the mire' = 'Holmes strove to avoid the mire'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth this analysis is based from CGEL. I don’t think they use terms such as “multi-word verbs”, “verb phrases” or “phrasal verbs” taking *to-infinitive complements* as the traditional grammars do - I think CGEL aims to be specific and accurate as possible.

Comment: In fact if you look at “Chapter 4: The clause: complements” (p. 274), they explicitly say: “*The term ‘phrasal verb’ implies that the combinations concerned form syntactic constituents belonging to the category verb. The view taken here, however, is that the underlined expressions in the [a] examples in [3], despite their idiomatic interpretations, donotformsyntacticconstituents, any more than the underlined wordsequencesinthe [b] examples form constituents. **It is for this reason that we do not use the term ‘phrasal verb’ in this grammar**.*”

Comment: But you're looking at and confusing two different constructions. Catenatives _John hastened to help them_ / _John made haste to help them_, **and** noun complements (complements of nouns) _John's vow to help them would eventually cost him his life._ Both obviously can be realised by to-infinitival clauses. And I'm analysing OP's example as the catenation.

Comment: 'a chain, or concatenation, of **verbs** followed ...'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth OK, I’ve taken your points into consideration. I think we can agree in: 1) I **took** action [to **make** my plan] | 2) **come** [to fruition] // in 2) “to fruition” is protypically a complement to the verb “come”, but in 1, “to make my plan” is a complement to the noun “action” (If you ignore the difference in terminology that CGEL does not use phrasal verbs like “took action”). However, there is still “a concatenation of verbs”: took >> make >> come “...followed by ‘non-finite complements’”.

Comment: If you compare 'take pains to', it is far clearer that we are dealing with a multi-word verb, with a similar meaning to 'strive to'. 'He took pains to ensure that the day would be a success.' You can't passivise ('*Pains to ensure that the day would be a success were taken by him'), and you can't substitute another simplex verb ( 'made / had / performed ... pains'). 'Take pains' is coherent, and takes a to-infinitive 'We took pains to build the shed properly'). 'Pains' is a fused part of the verbo-nominal, and we can't say " 'Pains' takes the complement 'to V ...'". I consider ...

Comment: 'take action [to]' a similar MWV, with 'take action' coherent.